# Converting a website's price to a number with no decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, price

I have a system that reads prices without decimals.

Example: 2890 = $28.90

I also have a system that takes a websites price of a product with the result being anywhere from $40.25 to just $40 (with no decimals places). I need most likely a regex or a function using javaScript or jQuery that would convert something like $40.25 to 4025 or $40 to 4000. Because I need to send the second system's returning number to the first system which will only except numbers without decimal places.

I originally thought I had it with this: item.price = `Number(item.price.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,"")*100);` where item.price in this case equals $79.99 but I got a result back as 7998.99999999 instead of 7999 which is what I need and I can't have those decimals places, so parseFloat isn't an option. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: The person that had the "item.price = parseInt(item.price.replace("$", "")) * 100;" was correct. That helped me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What you really wanted? Because you first say _from $40.25 to just $40_ and then _something like $40.25 to 4025 or $40 to 4000_. It is confusing for us.

Comment: I have two systems. One reads numbers without decimal places. So 2890 = $28.90 in that system. The other system reads prices from websites which equal (as an example) $40.25 or $40. I can see how you can be confused because I didn't explicitly mention that the second system ($40.25 or $40) needs to send that number to the first system (end result needs to be 4025 or 4000). Hopefully that clears things up. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel, use a library! Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-currency

```
import parseCurrency from 'parse-currency'

const foo = parseCurrency('$10.50')
console.log(foo) // 10.5 

const bar = parseCurrency('$1,000,000.25')
console.log(bar) // 1000000.25
```

Answer (score 0):

As Duncan mentioned, parse-currency library would be the way, but it is not enough for your problem. Let's make a better function...

```
function parseCurrency(amount) {
    var number = amount.replace(/[^\d|\.]/g, ''); // Removes everything that's not a digit or a dot
    var parsedToFloat = parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100); // Make a float number even it is an integer

    return parsedToFloat.toFixed(2); // Now make sure that it will have always 2 decimal places
}

// This will return the following results...
parseCurrency('$40');        // "40.00"
parseCurrency('$40.25');     // "40.25"
parseCurrency('$40,000.25'); // "40000.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for a number that won't be fixed, you can do something like that:

```js
const currencies = [
  '$40',
  '$45.25',
  '$45.251123456789',
  '$1,000',
  '$1,000.25'
];

function convertToNumber(currency) {
  const number = currency.replace(/[^\d|\.]/g, '');
  return parseFloat(parseFloat(number).toFixed(2)) * 100;
}

console.log(currencies.map(convertToNumber))
```